# What is the name of the book describing a prestige-class called 'Hawk' (I think)?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, product-identification

I vaguely remember reading this PDF for 3.0 or 3.5 that contained a description of a prestige-class.

The class was for close-combat oriented rogues and warriors who were relying on intimidating the groups of enemies by graphically slaughtering individual foes. One of the abilities described was biting off one enemy's finger and spitting it into another enemy's face. The high-level abilities went further, into disembowelment territory.

The name of the class was 'Hawks' or 'Falcons'. I remember it being a single word, most likely a name of some bird of prey. Googling the 'prestige class ' returns mostly homebrew and classes that use these birds.

The image accompanying the description was brown-ish and depicted a halflingy-looking rogue resting on the remains of a giant decapitated serpent or something.

It didn't require the character to be Evil for entry, and, as I now recall, was even specifically associated with some good-aligned deity. It was 'fight evil with fear' type of a good-aligned PrC.

It was ten or so years ago and it may have been a Web Enhancement or a preview, since I don't have it in my full-pdfs folder now. The book was not necessary WoTC(most likely wasn't) but had a decent graphical design and illustrations to sure be a commercial product.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found it in the ['Book of the Righteous' by Green Ronin](http://www.rpgnow.com/product/20694/Book-of-the-Righteous?it=1).

It describes a prestige class *Hawks of Urian* on page 43. It's a sneak attack progressing PrC. The art depicts a roguish fellow cutting the fallen large beast's throat (question is wrong on the 'resting' part). Signature abilities include *Bloody Murder* and *Inflict Horrible Wound*. *Non-evil* alignment requirement.

The full write-up on the church of Urian is available for download from publisher's site as promotional material, so that's where I have seen it.